# Listview/listbox scroll stop work

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, stackpanel

I need make a layout like this.

```
<Page>...
    <Grid>
      <Grid..definitions/> 
        <StackPanel>
          ...HeaderScreen Layout here
        <StackPanel>
        <ListView> (or Listbox)
           ... My listItemTemplate here...
        </ListView> (or /Listbox)
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In order, when i use this structure the listview is not scrolling. Removing the "StackPanel" block, the scroll work perfectly.
I tryied use "Grid", but it is not also working.
And i need a fix header on this screen.

### EDIT - SOLUTION

My code work when i replace `<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>` to `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListBox` requires a fixed height for the scroll to work. If you have given the `ListBox` inside a grid row with `Height = "Auto"` or inside a `StackPanel`, the `ListBox` will try to take the size as much as it is needed. This will prevent the scroll. If you have given a fixed height, it will take only that size and displays the rest of the items inside it through scrolling.

Comment: Hi @Bells, thx for the help.

I repaired using "*" in the RowDefitnitions